# Почему не определяются имя, размер и тип файлов

Tags: php, файлы

Ситуация такова:

Есть форма загрузки файлов. На странице-обработчике вот такой код:

```
echo $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
echo $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
echo $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
```

Почему-то для некоторых файлов размер, тип и имя определяется правильно,
для некоторых имя вообще не определяется, для некоторых размер определяется как 0.
Причём это не зависит от типа файла. Для одного JPEG всё правильно отображается,
для другого нет. Из-за чего может возникать такая проблема?

Comment: Если подозреваете, что файл большой, то почему бы не проверить на заведомо маленьком файле? Может проблема не там, где вы её пытаетесь найти.

Comment: Нет. Информация о файле получается после его загрузки на сервер, как tmp-файл.

Comment: php - он серверный язык, и доступа к вашему компьютеру не имеет, поэтому может обрабатывать файлы только на своей стороне

Comment: То есть мне никак не выдать сообщение о том, что файл слишком большой, пока он не загрузится? А зачем тогда здесь http://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php используется такая строчка <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />? Какова её роль? Я попробовал её использовать, но она никакой роли не играет.

Comment: Сообщит пользователю об ошибке можно просто:

    if($_FILES['userfile']['error'] == 0){
        // всё гуд, загружаем
    } else {
        echo 'Хьюстон! У нас проблемы!';
    }

Comment: Если файл по размеру подходящий, то всё гуд выводится. А если файл большой, то хъюстона почему-то не видать. Так что почему-то не работает. Может у меня ПХП на локалке меньше 4.2.0. Как версию ПХП можно проверить?

Comment: Информация:    phpinfo();P.S. Прочитайте - [на сером фоне](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php)? начинается со слов "**Скрытое поле MAX_FILE_SIZE**"

Comment: Не могу понять, что за проблема. Ваш код 

if($_FILES['userfile']['error'] == 0){
    // всё гуд, загружаем
} else {
    echo 'Хьюстон! У нас проблемы!';
}

при загрузке одних файлов работает, а при других нет.
Загружаю mp3 размером 7,5Мб, ошибка выдаётся. Загружаю
другой файл почти такого же размера, не выводится ничего.
Блин, что это такое?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще лучше выводить полностью массив для просмотра:

```
echo '<pre>'; echo print_r($_FILES['userfile']); echo '</pre>';
```

В этом массиве есть ключ error (как уже сказали выше), в нём возвращается [код ошибки](http://www.php.su/phphttp/?uerrcodes), если она есть.

Нужно не забывать, что размер загружаемого файла также указывается и в настройках php в значении upload_max_filesize. Если загружаемый файл больше этого значения, то вернется ошибка с кодом 1.

Указывая в форме "MAX_FILE_SIZE" мы просто говорим предпочитаемый размер для файлов загружаемых именно через эту форму. Это значение может быть меньше, чем указанное в upload_max_filesize. Если файл "весит" больше чем указанный "MAX_FILE_SIZE", то при загрузке вернется ошибка с кодом 2.

Comment: Вообще понять ничего не могу. Такая же проблема, которую я указал в последнем комментарии. Для некоторых файлов выводится массив, и ошибка 1. Для других файлов вообще массив не выводится.

Comment: Массив не выводится для файлов больше 8 Мб. И как в таком случае выводить сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: А может вам надо просто увеличить максимально допустимый размер файла? Тогда или в php.ini измените значения для:

    post_max_size = 20M
    upload_max_filesize = 20M

Или в .htaccess

    php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
    php_value post_max_size 20M

Comment: Ну может быть. прописал в .htaccess, всё сработало.